# Emacs - mark the word forward and backward

Tags: emacs

Basically what I am asking is the equivalent function to vim's vb(bbww...) and vw(wwbb...):

I want to bind my meta-j and meta-k to mark the word before and after current point. Simple.el provided the mark-word function, which I bind to meta-k. And I changed the mark-word function a bit to:

```
 (defun mark-backward (&optional arg   allow-extend) ;   
      (interactive "P\np")
      (cond ((and allow-extend
               (or (and (eq last-command this-command) (mark t))
                   (and transient-mark-mode mark-active)))
      (setq arg (if arg (prefix-numeric-value arg)
               (if (< (mark) (point)) -1 1)))
                   (set-mark
                       (save-excursion
                           (goto-char (mark))
                           (forward-word arg)
                           (point))))   
      (t   (push-mark  
        (save-excursion
        (backward-word (prefix-numeric-value arg))
        (point))      nil t)))) 
(global-set-key (kbd "M-k") 'mark-word) 
(global-set-key (kbd "M-j") 'mark-backward)
```

This kinda worked.  I want to undo some marking use the other key, how can I do that? (i.e. after I marked some word with M-k, I want to use M-j to unmark some word to left. Currently, when I hit M-j, emacs continue to mark forward).

Comment: Thanks, Rafe. Please forgive me. My firefox choked somewhat and I just cannot see the format bar. Errrgggg

Comment: @Ikahtz Do you want `C-SPC M-f` resp `C-SPC M-b` in one keystroke?

Comment: yep, really miss vim's visual mode... ;)

Comment: `M-S-b` and `M-S-f` does that on my system. Or `C-S-<left>` and `C-S-<right>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(defun my-mark-word (N)
  (interactive "p")
  (if (and 
       (not (eq last-command this-command))
       (not (eq last-command 'my-mark-word-backward)))
      (set-mark (point)))
  (forward-word N))


(defun my-mark-word-backward (N)
  (interactive "p")
  (if (and
       (not (eq last-command this-command))
       (not (eq last-command 'my-mark-word)))
      (set-mark (point)))
  (backward-word N))

(local-set-key (kbd "M-k") 'my-mark-word)

(local-set-key (kbd "M-j") 'my-mark-word-backward)
```

This should emulate VIMs behaviour (with other keystrokes, of course).

**Remark:** `M-j` is by default bound to `indent-new-comment-line` which is quite handy when writing commented blocks in source code. `M-k` is by default bound to `kill-sentence`.

Comment: This solves my problem perfectly. I rebind the indent-new-comment-line to C-cj. Thanks a lot~~

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `forward-word` with `backward-word` in one more place.

The code, however, still have problems selecting words to the left of the point.

Ps. Please edit your post -- the code posted is barely readable.

Comment: I tried that, which won't work. Anyway I reedited the code. The layout for lisp code seems to be not working well..