# How to replace a word in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

Given the following sentence:

> This is one two three.

When I move the cursor to the space between **one** and **two**, I would like to replace **two** with XXX.
I know there is a way in vi so that I can mark **two** as the modified string so that when I finish entering the new string and the new string replaces the **two** in-place.

// Update-1 //

The corresponding command in vi is 'cw'

Comment: The only difference to my solution I can recognize is, that you see the word as it is overwritten. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace a region in emacs with yank buffer contents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627289/how-to-replace-a-region-in-emacs-with-yank-buffer-contents)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would probably just use <kbd>M-d SPC X X X</kbd> (if the SPC is necessary depends on wether the cursor is placed directly after "one" or before "two") or <kbd>M-f M-DEL X X X</kbd>, but maybe that's not what you're looking for.

Ok, you didn't answer my comment, and didn't vote up an answer, so I guessed what you might like and here is a little hack:

```
(defun change-word (n)
  (interactive "p")
  (lexical-let ((old-window-configuration (current-window-configuration)))
    (clone-indirect-buffer "*edit-word*" t)
    (narrow-to-region (point) (save-excursion
                                (forward-word n)
                                (point)))
    (overwrite-mode 1)
    (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-c")
                   (lambda ()
                     (interactive)
                     (widen)
                     (let ((end-of-edit (point)))
                       (kill-buffer)
                       (set-window-configuration old-window-configuration)
                       (goto-char end-of-edit))))))
```

Invoke <kbd>M-x change-word</kbd> (or bind it to a key you like), edit the word, and type <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> when you're done. If you want to edit the next `n` words, give it a prefix argument (e.g. <kbd>M-3 M-x change-word</kbd> to change the next three words). It's not exactly the same -- You'll edit in another buffer -- but it comes close. Try and see if you like it. It is not a very elaborate solution. Maybe the best, and most emacs-style approach, would be to have something akin to isearch-mode, that highlights the changed region and so on. Note that you'll have to `(require 'cl)` because of `lexical-let`.

Another possibility would be something like this:

```
(defun change-word ()
  (interactive)
  (dotimes (i (- (save-excursion (end-of-thing 'word)) (point)))
    (insert (read-char))
    (delete-char 1)))
```

But this example is just a very crude hack -- You won't even be able to navigate while editing your word. Maybe one could write something modifying the command-loop behavior, but I didn't look into that.

I don't know about any built-in functionality that does exactly what you seem to want, but of course there are Viper and other Vi emulation modes built in.

Comment: It seems that there is no easy internal solution for this. For now, I would like to just use **alt+d** to delete the word and enter the new word.

Comment: Note that doing so adds the deleted word to the *kill ring*, which can be annoying.

Answer (score 5):

With the cursor before the letter `t` in "two," press <kbd>M-@</kbd> or <kbd>C-M-Space</kbd> to select the word "two," and then type <kbd>XXX</kbd> to replace it. In my Emacs, <kbd>M-@</kbd> is bound to [`mark-word`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/emacs/Marking-Objects.html), and <kbd>C-M-Space</kbd> is bound to [`mark-sexp`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/emacs/Marking-Objects.html). I find the latter easier to type, but the former is more likely to work as intended across various modes.

The nice thing about these commands is that repeated executions (via the aforementioned key sequences) *extend* the selection incrementally. In your case, the first press of <kbd>M-@</kbd> highlights "two":

> This is one |*two* three.

Pressing <kbd>M-@</kbd> again highlights "three" as well:

> This is one |*two three*.

On your keyboard, the meta key (denoted by "M" in these examples) may be bound to the Alt key.

Comment: And, of course, you can use prefix arguments with `mark-word`: `M-3 M-@` selects the next three words.

Answer (score 1):

The [following SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216300/emacs-mark-the-word-forward-and-backward/5219092#5219092) deals specifically with reproducing vim's word marking behavior. Then it's just a matter of killing the region (<kbd>C-w</kbd>) before typing.

Answer (score 1):

For the over all document editing in multiple cases like this, you might want to use  M-x delete-selection-mode.  You can just select the 2nd word and start typing. Use *C-M-SPACE* (mark-sexp) for selection.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it sounds like `M-backspace` would delete the 'two' and leave the cursor ready to type in the replacement.