# emacs word replace not working for me?

Tags: emacs

Following this thread;

[How to replace a word in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060946/how-to-replace-a-word-in-emacs/16492625#16492625)

to replace a word, when I issue M-@ it selects the word but when I begin typing the new text the selection disappears and the new text is inserted in front of, instead of replacing, the original word. Why?

Comment: because emacs is designed so.

Comment: @gongzhitaao Why bother answering if you will not provide any meaningful content.

Comment: @javadba Since Greg has all already answered it :)

Answer (score 6):

When you issue M-@, it only makes a selection. You either need to kill the word, or you can enable delete-selection-mode.